# Free/libre equivalent fonts for a cover

Tags: fonts, open-source

I'm working on a book cover for a translated book. I want to keep the style of the original book, but I'd also like to use free/libre fonts if possible.

Using the original fonts, this is what it looks like:

[image: original fonts]

The two fonts in white are Latino Elongated and Goldwater.

Can you think of a pair of free/libre (ideally PD, GNU GPL or OFL) serif fonts that could replace these two fonts?

**Note 1:** The top one is also used for chapter headings in the book and should ideally have standard ligatures and small caps.

**Note 2:** The book uses Linux Libertine as the main inside font, and EB Garamond Italic as the section heading font, is that makes a difference.

**Edit:**

Since it's hard to find free/libre serif narrow fonts, I decided to try with sans-serif fonts, so now I have this (using Steelfish and Tulpen One):

[image: sans fonts]

Is this a good replacement (I'm really quite bad at graphics). What else would you suggest?

Comment: @koiyu: thanks for the edit, I meant OFL indeed :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's $80 total for both typefaces, if you love 'em, buy 'em!

That said, for *Charismatique*, you could try Bodoni XT, which you can condense and kern manually:
[image: ...]

As for *Charismaniaque*, there aren't many compatible free offerings. Edition Serif by Diehl and SF Covington (non-commercial) could work here, but if you're going that route, might as well buy Goldwater.

Comment: Right, it's 80€ and we're a small association with very little budget ;-) Funny, I had actually tried Bodoni XT as a replacement for Goldwater, but I wasn't very convinced. Since the first font is used inside the book, I don't mind so much paying 30€ for it, but the second font I use only for this single word, and I'm really not sure to use again for anything, so 50€ for one single word...

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried an easy web search before asking such a question!
There aren't a lot of OpenSource fonts, so if you don't really need it (not a full OpenSource project), you should use free fonts, there are millions on the web. But if it's really important to you, check the [Open Font Library](http://openfontlibrary.org/).

Comment: I am fully aware of where to find free and open-source fonts online, and such a question might not even belong here. My problem is not to find them, but to *choose* them, which is more of a graphic design issue I think.